# Oracle ID, PK and FK Database Schema

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have very simple question. All I want to do, is to create a database schema.

[image: Database Schema]

- Table `PLANT` has two columns: `PLANT_ID` (primary key) and `NAME` which comes from `KNIME`.
- Table `PRODUCTION` also has two columns: a primary key and `NAME` which also comes from `KNIME`.

What I want is that the `PLANT_ID` column should be also in the `PRODUCTION` table.  How can I do this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  The simple answer to "how can I do this" is -- you include that column in your CREATE TABLE statement.  But I suspect your real question is something else.

Comment: What is KNIME? Rename PLANT_PLANT_ID to PLANT_ID if you want that column name

Comment: @Dave PLANT_ID is set on ' automatic incrementing', so that the Table PLANT adds automatic a PLANT_ID when the a NAME get´s added. I would like to see the PLAt_ID in the table  PRODUCTION as well. For instance - if I would like to join that table...

Comment: @eckes KNIME is tool for data preparation https://www.knime.org

Answer (score 0):

it is unclear as to what you want; the requirements should be specified in terms of the relationships between the entities Plant and Production.  PRODUCTION could hold ID for PLANT (if a production entity could have one plant) [or vice versa].  It really depends on the carnality of the relationship between Plant and Production.  If Production can have one and only Plant, then just put the plant_id column in Production table (i.e. a foreign key).  If it is many-to-many (i.e. a Production entity can have many Plants or a plant entity can have many relationships to production entity) then you need an "intersection entity", say Plant_Production that has only plant_id and Production_id (and maybe a description of the relationship if the business requirements dictate).

Comment: I think you mean "cardinality".  Although I kind of like "carnality of the relationship".

Comment: @DaveCosta Good one!  That's what I get for trying to answer questions around midnight.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is how to create a database constraint such that `PRODUCTION.PLANT_PLANT_ID` always references a row in `PLANT`.

To do this you need to:

1. Add a primary key to the `PLANT` table.
2. Add a foreign key from `PRODUCTION(PLANT_PLANT_ID)` to `PLANT`

See: [Alter Table Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001) for both of these.